# All wireless networks suddenly disappear every once in a while a Lenovo Thinkpad X201s running Windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I’m using Windows 7 on a [Lenovo Thinkpad X201s](http://support.lenovo.com/en/documents/pd010141) and lately—about every 15-60 minutes—my wireless Internet connection disappears. When it does this I can’t find any other wireless network, though such networks exist.

Only after rebooting the system, does it go back to normal and can find wireless networks. But only for a while and 15-60 minutes later it’s disconnected again, not finding any wireless network.

What could be happening?

Comment: Sounds like a broken wireless adapter, or antenna.  But it could basically be anything based on the little information provided. What steps have you already tried in attempting to rectify your problem?  Where are you getting stuck?  "Superuser is for computer enthusiasts and power users" not front-line tech support, you'll need to do a little work first. :)

Comment: If all wireless networks are vanishing entirely it's likely a faulty wlan adapter. No ip information will help since it is a complete loss of connection. I would verify this isn't happening on Ethernet to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: @snakile: This is an old question and it looks like you didn't respond to any of the questions or answers.  By now, I assume the question has been overtaken by events.  It would be good to put it to bed, though.  Did you solve the problem?  If so, can you post an answer as to the fix (which would help others)?  If not, and the problem no longer exists, it would be impossible for anyone to provide a definitive answer, in which case, the question should probably be closed.  Can you update the status?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not answerable without OP clarification.  The problem is long overtaken by events and it appears the OP has abandoned the question.

Answer (score 0):

Interference!

If you have a cordless phone then this would be my number one suspect. WiFi and many cordless phones operate in or near the 2.4 GHz bandwidth (or have harmonics that can interfere). Baby monitors and even fluorescent lights might cause interference too. Then again, if there are people or objects moving in front of your access point that too can cause a temporary loss of signal. It's not very likely since the very nature of the 2.4GHz and especially the 5GHz band are relatively immune from disturbances like that. But it's still a possibility.

More likely might be your system's power settings. Have you checked that you haven't enabled your power settings to turn off WiFi when it isn't being used?

Another possibility might be NIC and/or DHCP settings. Is your NIC confused or trying to use IPV6 (where there is none)? Maybe your router has it's DHCP renewal policy set to something odd. Then again, maybe your ISP is fiddling with IPv4 addresses and your routers NAT can't keep up. To determine what's going on I usually like to see if I can at least get to my routers administration page (usually 192.168.1.1).

One other thing may simply be your connection and the use of whatever "phone book" is being used to look up Internet addresses. For that, I'd be looking at changing my DNS settings. (I might suggest OpenDNS at http://www.opendns.com - their addresses are 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.)

I really can't say why any of this is happening or if those are things to even be concerned with. But at least it's a start. Hope it helps...

Comment: Interference, unlikely as a reboot seems to resolve the issue.  DHCP/IPv6/DNS, again not likely since the OP specifically mentions not being able to see any wireless networks (not that he can't access the internet, etc).  Power settings may be a real possibility, but most likely then in conjunction with a driver or hardware issue.